# How to divide Days Duration into further smaller sections in Python

Tags: python, pandas, spyder

```
'''

import pandas as pd

import pymysql as sql

import pygsheets

import datetime

#%%

today =datetime.date.today()
month=today.month
year =today.year
d =today.day

#%%

date =datetime.datetime.now().date() - pd.to_timedelta("90day")

date_filter =datetime.datetime.strftime(date,'%Y-%m-%d')

#%%

db = sql.connect(host = 'ffff', 
                 user = 'aadsd', 
                 password ='#######',
                 database = 'ewewewe')

cursor=db.cursor()
cursor.execute(f"""select * from table1 t1
left join table2  t2 on t1.id=t2.id
where t2.name ='xct' and date(addtime(t1.created_on,"05:30:00"))>{date}; """)
'''
```

I am new to Python , I have defined **{date}** which in the last cell as

**date** = datetime.datetime.now().date() - pd.to_timedelta("**90day**") ,

I want to split 90 Day part into first 45 day and Next 45 day concept in another cell as currently I am facing issues with error  of "maximum statement execution time exceeded" due to large number of DB records

Answer (score 0):

you can use this to split date to any size

```py
import datetime
#%%

now = datetime.datetime.now()

date_filter =datetime.datetime.strftime(date,'%Y-%m-%d')

#%%
bin_size = 5
for i in range(90,0,-bin_size):
    end_date = now.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
    start_date = now-datetime.timedelta(days=bin_size)
    now = start_date
    start_date = start_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
    
    print(f"""select * from table1 t1
left join table2  t2 on t1.id=t2.id
where t2.name ='xct' and date(addtime(t1.created_on,"05:30:00")) between {start_date} and {end_date}; """)
```

result like this

```
select * from table1 t1
left join table2  t2 on t1.id=t2.id
where t2.name ='xct' and date(addtime(t1.created_on,"05:30:00")) between 2021-06-11 and 2021-06-16; 
select * from table1 t1
left join table2  t2 on t1.id=t2.id
where t2.name ='xct' and date(addtime(t1.created_on,"05:30:00")) between 2021-06-06 and 2021-06-11; 
select * from table1 t1
left join table2  t2 on t1.id=t2.id
where t2.name ='xct' and date(addtime(t1.created_on,"05:30:00")) between 2021-06-01 and 2021-06-06;
...
```

if you want sql query faster.replace `date(addtime(t1.created_on,"05:30:00"))` to `t1.created_on` if possible.
use python time shift ie change start_date and end_date do reduce hours would be better.